# Kill thread on close

Tags: java, multithreading, jpanel

I have a constructor of a JFrame where I have a Thread(t1) which is running thanks to a

```
    while(true)
```

I would like to know how to implement my JFrame so it can kill the thread when I close it, because t1 need to be running when the JFrame is active

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
public class Vue_Session extends JFrame {
private  JPanel contentPane;
private int idsess;
private User u;

public Vue_Session(User us, int id) {
    this.u = us;
    this.idsess = id;
    toServ t=new toServ(idsess);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds((int) screenSize.getWidth() / 2 - 800 + (800 / 2), 90, 800,
            600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Vue_Idee vueIdee = new Vue_Idee(this.idsess, this.u);
    contentPane.add(vueIdee, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Vue_IdeeSession vueSess = new Vue_IdeeSession(this.idsess);
    contentPane.add(vueSess, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Thread t1 = new Thread( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                t.getIdee();
                vueSess.act();
                revalidate();
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
}
```

Comment: `he` as in? And where did the Thread come from. Provide complete code that makes some sense.

Comment: Hi there, This post is lacking detail. Please add further explanations and code snippets. What are you trying to achieve? What is the problem? What is the error?

Comment: I think you should simply assign a null to it

Comment: @AniketThakur he as it , sorry i'm not english and a little tired.

Comment: @MarkButler there isn't any error , but I need to have a Thread in my JFrame(which will refresh some information) but I Would like to kill it only when the user close the JFrame

Comment: @KickButtowski I have edit my post, so maybe you will understand more what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it with a boolean variable like

```
boolean end = false;
while (!end){...}
```

Also I suggest you use **ExecutorService** or **ForkJoinPool** so you can simply control your tasks, threads, etc

EDIT:

```
boolean end = false;

new Thread(() -> {
    while (!end) {
        //...
    }
}).start();
```

and this is where you should end your tasks:

```
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        end = true;
        System.exit(0);
        // or this.dispose();
    }
});
```

good luck :)

Comment: @user3745832 was this helpful?

Comment: Oh I didn't see your edit, but as it is what I need to do, I will accept it!

Comment: Just in case someone else come by:
don't forget to put
    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 0):

It's a controversial topic but in general I would replace the `while (true)` construct with

```
       while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            t.getIdee();
            vueSess.act();
            revalidate();
        }
```

More information on this topic can be found here:

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here was the answer:
I needed to add en WindowListenne:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent b) {

        t1.stop();
        dispose();

    }

});
```

And also:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make the thread kill-able. To do this, instead of looping forever, loop as long as certain looping flag is true.

After that, you need to create a listener that gets called whenever the user closes the frame. You can use `WindowAdapter` to do this. When the listener is called, set the looping flag to false. Once the thread dies, you can safely terminate the program.

For example:

```
public class Vue_Session extends JFrame {

    Thread thread = null;
    boolean threadAlvie = true;
    boolean threadDie = false;

    public Vue_Session(User us, int id) {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                threadAlive = false;
                // Wait until the thread dies
                while (!threadDie) {
                  // Sleep for 100 milliseconds.
                  Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                while (threadAlive){
                  // do something
                }
                threadDie = true;
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```